# Como implementar a função strcpy sem utilizar a biblioteca <string> em c++?

Tags: c++

Não consegui desenvolver um código eficaz, uma vez que não domino a linguagem como deveria.
Não sai dessa parte :
char *strcopy(char *destino, char *origem)

Comment: Você já tentou algo? Já leu a documentação da função? Conseguiu achar a documentação dela?

Comment: Não consegui achar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A documentação diz que a função strcpy faz o seguinte:

> Copies the character string pointed to by src, including the null terminator, to the character array whose first element is pointed to by dest.

Portanto, com um simples while, copio a origem para o destino até copiar o null terminator '\0'.

```
char* strcpy2(char* dest, const char* source)
{
    int i = 0;

    while ((dest[i] = source[i]) != '\0')
    {
        i++;
    }

    return dest;
}
```

Comment: Qual o propósito deste código? Poderia explicar a relevância dele com o contexto da pergunta?

Comment: Se eu entendi bem, ele quer implementar a função strcpy "na mão" e não está conseguindo. Acima está uma possível implementação.

Comment: É de uma lista que estou respondendo para estudo. É exatamente isso, Arthur, Muito obrigado!

Comment: @ArthurPassos, poderia explicar como chegou nessa solução? Para que quem chegue aqui consiga entender a resolução, e não apenas replicar código?

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Fiz o possível. É um código extremamente simples, chega a ser difícil de explicar.